# Identify html data-attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items that is iterated in a foreach in Razor and for every item I have an anchor that opens a bootstrap modal with the id of the item, but for every item that is open, the data attribute of the first item id is always shown, what I need is identify data-id attribute in Javascript to show the item id of every item, this is my html:

```
<a href="#viewItem" id="item" data-toggle="modalViewItem" data-item-id="@Item.ItemId"> Ver</a>
```

And in Javascript

```
'<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + $("#item").data("item-id") '</h4>'
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Do you duplicate `id="item"` with your foreach loop?

Comment: No, every item in html have a different item-id, but when i get it in Javascript, no matter wich anchor I click, always send me back the value of the first

Comment: can you provide html around your link? now, as say @Jasen, `id` attribute always equal `item` so you change only `data-item-id`

Comment: @Jasen Sorry, I don't understood correctly your question, but yes, the id of every item it's equals to item (id="item"), the only value that change is data-item-id, I changed the $("#item").data("item-id") for $(this).data("item-id") as Samuel Cook suggest me and it worked, thank you all for your answers

Comment: Duplicate `id` values is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#item` will always return the first instance that is found in the document.

Presumably you have created a `click` event which then inserts the `<h4>` html. If this is the case then you can use `this` as you are creating an instance of that element:

`'<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + $(this).data("item-id")+ '</h4>'`

Comment: thank you so much, i need to learn a lot of Javascript yet, this answer solve my problem, thank you.